# Copy output data from Custom Activity Powershell script

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-data-factory

I have created a Custom Activity on ADF v2 that runs a Powershell script running the command “powershell .\script.ps1”.

Actually, the output of the script is saved on “StaName/adfjobs/activityRunId/stdout.txt” but I need to store the file in another container on the same StorageAccount, for exemple “StaName/outputs/stdout.txt”.

¿What’s the best way to perform this?
Create a Copy activity to copy the file? or there’s some method to send data directly to “StaName/outputs/” through the powershell script?

Comment: If your script is not specifying the path for the output file, it will save in the current working directory. Please show us the relevant part of that script so we can help you.

Comment: @Theo,

Using:

`$table | format-table -AutoSize` 

`$table | Export-Csv 'test.csv'`

I obtain the results in two files:

test.csv -> "https://XXXX.francecentral.batch.azure.com/jobs/adfv2-pbipool/tasks/ZZZZZ/files/wd/test.csv"

stdout.text -> "https://XXXX.francecentral.batch.azure.com/jobs/adfv2-pbipool/tasks/ZZZZZ/files/stdout.txt"

stdout.txt file is accesible from my StorageAccount and test.csv not.

I have two solutions in mind:
Do a copy activity to copy stdout.txt to another container, or try to send text.csv directly to the destination storageaccount if it's possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a copy activity to copy output file to the other container.

You can find my answer here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5ceda984-874e-417b-8a28-7a512ede61d0/custom-activity-output-values-for-use-in-sequential-task?forum=AzureDataFactory to read from the script blob.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I was trying with FilePath `adfjobs/@activity('CustomActivity').ActivityRunId/output/'`and then I was getting the error " ContainerName: https://stapowerbimu.blob.core.windows.net/adfjobs," with the curly bracket it works fine!