# ADF - Pipeline with powershell script

Tags: azure, powershell, csv, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I have written a small Powershell script in order to retrieve some information from my organization and export this into a .csv file:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {company -Like "*COMPANYNAME*"} -Properties department | Select sAMAccountName, department, userprincipalname | export-csv -path C:\temp\test.csv
```

My aim is to create a pipeline in Azure Data Factory, in order to launch this script and export the csv into a dataset, so that I can get all the data within SQL Azure.

How could I create the pipeline and insert this script?

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run a PowerShell script by creating a DataFactory with a Custom Activity that runs the command: `powershell .\script.ps1`
You must copy script.ps1 in the StorageAccount linked with your custom activity.

To copy Activity Output you can follow this thread https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5ceda984-874e-417b-8a28-7a512ede61d0/custom-activity-output-values-for-use-in-sequential-task?forum=AzureDataFactory, it worked for me.
And find some extra info here: [Copy output data from Custom Activity Powershell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53518485/copy-output-data-from-custom-activity-powershell-script)

Comment: Thank you so much RuanoLin!

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/19119145-powershell-script-support-in-activity), `Powershell Script` can't be run directly in the adf pipeline so far. Maybe you could vote up this thread.

You could configure `custom activity` from this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-dotnet-custom-activity#custom-activity) to run your ps script, also you could follow this [github tutorial](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/data-factory/v1/data-factory-use-custom-activities.md) to create c# custom activity.